# Pointer error: C++

Tags: pointers, c++11

I am getting an error on the following line and I am sure it has something to do with pointers:

```
 if(x->getP() == z->getP()->getP()->getL())
```

The getters are:

```
 template <class A, class B> N<A,B>& N<A,B>:: getL() {
    return *l;
}

template <class A, class B> N<A,B>& N<A,B>:: getP() {
    return *p;
}
```

The error is on the RHS of the if statement. Could anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Member reference type N<int,int> is not a pointer

Comment: Then refer to the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning references, not pointers. The right operator to use is `.`, not `->`.

```
z->getP().getP().getL()
```

(Assuming `z` itself is a pointer.)